# Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.5.RELEASE' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I got this message in my pom file. Should I need to add or remove any dependency or plugin inside my pom? It looks like maven is not recognizing the Spring Boot version.
thanks in advance. I've already tried to remove and add some dependencies but the error still persists.

Pom File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.algaworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>artigo-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>artigo-spring-boot</name>
    <description>Projeto de exemplo para o artigo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3 - maven version
Java version: 14.0.1 - java version

Comment: Can you check your .m2 repository?  Is spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.5.RELEASE.pom there? If not check your maven configuration.

Comment: Are you building on plain command line?

Comment: Did you try right Klick in pom.xml and then maven->reimport

Comment: Or do a mvn clean and then reimport dependencies?

Comment: Hey, guys, sorry for not answering before. O got it. I reimport and update maven.
Thanks all.